# Motivating notation that looks like the probability of differentials

Tags: expected-value, notation

[*The Elements of Statistical Learning*](https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/) exemplifies a notation (which I have occasionally seen elsewhere) that I would like clarification on. From page 18:

$$\operatorname{EPE}(f) = \int [y - f(x)]^2 \color{red}{Pr(dx,dy)}$$

I would have understood $\color{blue}{dG_{X,Y}(x,y)}$ or $\color{magenta}{g_{X,Y}(x,y) dx\ dy}$ where $G$ and $g$ are the CDF and PDF respectively. When it comes to differentials I see them in some contexts as very tiny changes, and in others I think about them as unit basis vectors in tangent space. I keep interpreting $\color{red}{Pr(dx,dy)}$ as the probability of such tangent vectors, but I cannot seem to make any useful sense of that in this context.

Since the text also tells us that we are considering a statistical expectation, it must be equivalent to $\color{blue}{dG_{X,Y}(x,y)}$ and $\color{magenta}{g(x,y) dx\ dy}$ under an assumption of smoothness of the CDF. Without an assumption of smoothness we could have also written $$\int_0^{\infty}[y - f(x)]^2(1- G(x,y))dx\ dy - \int_{-\infty}^0 [y - f(x)]^2G(x,y) dx\ dy.$$

Is there an **intuition** or **motivation** behind this notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree that it is equivalent with $dG_{X,Y}(x,y)$ but the notation $g(x,y)dx\,dy$ presumes that the PDF $g(x,y)$ exists, which is not always the case.

I think it is just notation for integration over the joint distribution.

Comment: I agree that expectations can be calculated without the use of the density function, which is useful when the density doesn't exist, note that $dG_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the differential of the CDF which is equivalent to the density multiplied by the differentials via a chain-rule property. Smoothness is already assumed. It is already clear from the text that the author was just writing the expectation operator in a different way. The substance of my question is to obtain an intuition or motivation for the notation because I find it a perplexing distraction every time I see it.

Comment: The "d" in notations of integrals like $\int f dx$ doesn't necessarily refer to differentials. If you write e.g. $d\mu$  it doesn't mean that $\mu$ is a differentiable function.

Comment: I would think $dx$ and $d\mu$ are elements of the tangent space rather than smooth functions *per se*. If I see a "d" in front of a function, such as $dF(x)$, I don't have any other interpretation of that than to take it as the differential of that function. Can you explain how this is related to the substance of the function?

Comment: IIUC, the substance of your question is that you want to get an understanding of the motivation for this notation. And my point is that there is no particular motivation, it is just notation. If you refer to the theory of integration of differential forms on manifolds, then there you have indeed proper differentials. But this is not as general as measure theoretic integration and the integrals over those forms, too, are eventually defined by ordinary measure theoretic integrals which don't use notions like differentials.

Comment: Okay, I follow that.

Comment: As someone who studied differential geometry intensively for years, I am unconvinced.  There's a fundamental problem with this notation: *it does not refer to $x$ or $y.$* A notation of the form $G(x,y;\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y)$ would work to refer to some kind of joint probability constructed from, or related to, univariate measures $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y.$  If differential forms are intended then it is *crucial* that $G$ be allowed to depend on $x$ and $y.$ I have always understood much of the notation in ESL as being informal shorthand--but it works poorly here.

Comment: @whuber What are you unconvinced of? I did not mean to say that the notation was meant to be understood as differential forms. Quite the contrary, my point was, too, that the notation is rather informal and the "d" should not be understood as referring to a real differential.